# angularjs services and controllers data out of sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I've got what I thought was a fairly simple AngularJS application. I used to have a simple countdown timer in my controller code, but I decided to break it out into its own service. That's where the problems began.

Previously, when my timer code was embedded within the controller, the `countdown` scope variable displayed correctly - every second, it would count down one less, until 0, as per the timer function. However, now that I've moved this to a service, and been passing the data back and forth with some function calls, the `countdown`variable counts down 2 numbers every second, rather than 1. If I `console.log(countdown);` in my service's `rundownClock()` function, the correct countdown number is displayed each pass, however: 10,9,8,7...to 1.

Can anyone figure out what I'm now doing wrong, and why this "double counting" is occurring? Am I not maintaining the scope correctly in the controller?

Here is some of the controller, with the relevant CountdownService bits highlighted:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'CountdownService', function($scope, CountdownService) {

    // TIMER SERVICES
    $scope.startTimer = CountdownService.startTimer;

    $scope.runClock = function () {

        $scope.updateCountdown();

        if (($scope.countdown > 0) && ($scope.roundStarted == true)) {
            CountdownService.rundownClock($scope.countdown);
        }
    };

    $interval($scope.runClock, 1000);

    $scope.updateCountdown = function () {

        CountdownService.setCurrentRound($scope.currentRound);
        $scope.countdown = CountdownService.getCountdown();
        $scope.roundStarted = CountdownService.getRoundStarted();

    }

    }]);
```

Here's some of the service in question. (Don't worry about the rounds variable set-up at the beginning, it's not relevant to the problem):

```
myApp
    .factory("CountdownService", function (gameSetUp) {

        var rounds = gameSetUp.rounds,
            roundStarted = false,
            roundFinished = false,
            currentRound = 0,
            countdown = rounds[currentRound].time;

        // grab the round from the controller's scope to set the current round
        function setCurrentRound(round) {
            currentRound = round;
        }

        function getRoundStarted() {
            return roundStarted;
        }

        function getCountdown() {
            return countdown;
        }

        function startTimer() {
            roundStarted = true;
        }

        function rundownClock() {

            if (roundStarted === true) {

                if (countdown > 0) {
                    countdown = countdown - 1;
                }

                if (countdown === 0) {
                    roundFinished = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            startTimer: startTimer,
            rundownClock: rundownClock,
            getCountdown: getCountdown,
            getRoundStarted: getRoundStarted,
            setCurrentRound: setCurrentRound
        };
    });
```

And finally, a snippet from the view, where the countdown scope variable is displayed:

```
<div class="timer md-body-2">{{ countdown }} seconds</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn'y in Controller be CountdownService.startTimer()?

Comment: What about to use "new Date().getTime() / 1000" to store the initial second, and to get elapsed seconds?

Comment: @cyan no, since that is actually called onClick by a different part of the view. A little odd, but it's how it works... :)

Comment: rundownClock has no parameter but is called with parameter.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo yeah, I prob should have started with using elapsed time, but I did it the way I did it .. would appreciate any advice on why the data is out of sync b/w the controller and service though. any clue?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov good shout, but that doesn't fix the double counting issue. any clues?

Comment: Ok. You can try to put the $interval on service too, and simplify the usage for the controller... I believe the controller access should be something like CountdownService.count(seconds, callbackFunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update @downvoter :**

[Here is a working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UWV88aV1bJCuIT9MxIE?p=preview) ( without using controller in 2 places route and template)

[Here is the exact behavior that the author is talking about](http://plnkr.co/edit/fSbnJvUsJhArUQYi9cul?p=preview) (**using controller in route and template**)

**My original answer**

I think your `myCtrl` controller is running twice, so, your `$interval($scope.runClock, 1000);` is running twice also ...

Are using registering `myCtrl` as route controller and in your template with ng-controller ?

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you're saying, and you're completely right. :) I was using ```ng-controller=myCtrl"``` as well as the ```ng-view```. Problem solved! Life saver!